# How to do function compose

Tags: python, list, function

I want to do function compose for example

I have the function `double_list(list)` that does

`double_list([[1]]) >>> [[1],[1]]` and I want to make a recursive function that will compose double list n times for example `recursion(doublelist, 2) >>> [[1],[1],[1],[1]]` instead of doing `double_list(double_list([[1]]))` I tried a lot of things none of them worked all the times i get `[[1],[1]]` is there a **recursive** way to do that without using any module?

This is what I tried:

```
def recursion(k, lst):
if k > 0:
    return recursion(k-1, lst)
lst = double_list(lst)
return lst
```

Comment: Can u include what you have tried in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
def double_list(ls):
    ls.extend([i[:] for i in ls])
    return ls

def recursion(k, lst):
    if k > 0:
        return recursion(k-1, double_list(lst))
    return lst
print(recursion(2, [[1]]))
```

Will return

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Comment: what i did was `return recursion(k-1, lst)` instead of `return recursion(k-1, *double_list(lst)*)` so it didn't return lst I meant to. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
def recursion(func, arg, n):
    if n>1:
        return recursion(func, func(arg), n-1)
    else:
        return func(arg)

print(recursion(double_list, [[1]], 2))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26216280)